# Change style of an element in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

Goal: Change style of an element in a forEach loop
Issue: Style not being applied

In my loop, if I console.log(element), I do get the right list of filtered elements.
Running this works, but I want my function to modify every element that match my filter:

```
let contentPreview = document.querySelectorAll('.o_last_message_preview');
contentPreview[0].style.color = 'yellow'
```

All elements are correctly assigned.

```
function changeNotificationColor() {
        // Notification button that opens list of notifications
        let notifyButton = document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle.o-no-caret[title="Conversations"]');

            notifyButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // List of notifications - each notification is contained in a .o_last_message_preview class
            let contentPreview = document.querySelectorAll('.o_last_message_preview');

            contentPreview.forEach(function (element) { if (element.innerText.includes('Marine')) {element.style.color = 'yellow'}})
        })
    }

changeNotificationColor();
```

HTML Notifications Dropdown button:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle o-no-caret" data-toggle="dropdown" data-display="static" aria-expanded="true" title="Conversations" href="#" role="button">
                <i class="o_mail_messaging_menu_icon fa fa-comments" role="img" aria-label="Messages"></i> <span class="o_notification_counter badge badge-pill">366</span>
            </a>
```

HTML template of a notification node (each notification creates one of these nodes):

```
<div class="o_preview_info">
                <div class="o_preview_title">
                    <span class="o_preview_name">
                        You have been assigned to Backorder xx
                    </span>
                    <span class="o_preview_counter">
                        &nbsp;(1)
                    </span>
                    
                    <span class="o_last_message_date ml-auto mr-2"> 3 minutes ago </span>
                </div>
                <div class="o_last_message_preview">
                    
                        
                            Marine 
                    
                </div>
                <span title="Mark as Read" class="o_discuss_icon o_mail_preview_mark_as_read fa fa-check"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please, provide some HTML Markups so we can debug and help you.

Comment: @Mina I have updated the post with an HTML sample of the component.

Comment: Where is the `dropdown-toggle.o-no-caret` class?

Comment: @Mina Added it to the post.

Comment: I just test it and it works fine, please check. https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/c54f37g6/2/

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your issue is, but it's not in the code that you showed; this works fine:

```js
let contentPreview = document.querySelectorAll('.o_last_message_preview');

contentPreview.forEach(function (element) { if (element.innerText.includes('Marine')) {element.style.color = 'yellow'}})
```

```html
<div class="o_last_message_preview">This contains Marine</div>
<div class="o_last_message_preview">This does not</div>
<div class="o_other_message_preview">This has a different class</div>
```

Comment: _"I don't know what your issue is, but it's not in the code that you showed;"_ - Then why an answer? Close as _"Needs debugging details"_ or _"Needs details or clarity"_

Comment: @Andreas I know that at best it's on the edge of what's allowed, but I wanted to demonstrate using a provably working snippet, to give OP something to build upon. Comments can't have snippets, and editing the question to add such a snippet would be too invasive.

Comment: There are hundreds of playgrounds that allow to share your edits: jsbin.com, jsfiddle.com, codepen.io, repl.it, ...

Comment: I fully support Thomas's argument. Closing questions before they have been properly understood is too often the practice here. Be kind!

Comment: The "playgrounds" you mentioned @Andreas are not of the same quality as SO's snippets. They don't run well on smartphones for example.

Comment: _"Closing questions before they have been properly understood..."_ - If the question lacks information than you should vote to close. That's literally the reason why there's such an close-vote option o.O A closed question is not a punishment...

Comment: _"The "playgrounds" you mentioned @Andreas are not of the same quality as SO's snippets."_ - So every answer with a snippet is valid because it can be viewed on a mobile phone?

Comment: @ben You don't need to share _all_ the HTML, just enough to reproduce the issue, ideally in a snippet as I did above. If the code as given in the question works fine, there is a piece of context that is missing, so the question becomes unanswerable. Something for next time! :)

Comment: _"...there is a piece of context that is missing, so the question becomes unanswerable."_ - And yet you added an answer...

Comment: @Thomas I need to learn how it works around here. Either there is too much info or not enough.